# В Webview не работает автовход

Tags: android, webview

Не работает авто-вход на сайт в `WebView`.

1. Куки включены.
2. В обычном браузере всё работает.

Comment: на чего будем гадать - то? Может вы нам покажете какой то част кода или чего угодно, что бы понят ваш вопрос...

Comment: Покажите как и что вы делаете, а лучше сразу с тестовым акком чтоб сразу проверили и дали точный ответ.

Comment: Ну код...могу просто сказать что имеем WebView...вклбчено абсолютно всё...но автологин не пашет...

Comment: я может ошибаюсь, но это вроде как такая политика "запомнить логин/пасс для автовхода в WebView нельзя".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню, это делалось с помощь [`webview.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setSavePassword(boolean)).

Но, начиная с API 18, этот метод deprecated и больше не будет работать. Единственный костыль, который я вижу возможным - это сохранять локально логин/пароль и а потом самому в `onLoad` страницы заполнять. Но это очень очень не секьюрно.